# How to get rid of Text Channels from channel list in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, channel

Here I have some examle code:

```
for server in client.servers:
        for channel in server.channels:
            print(channel)
```

And the output is for example:

```
Text Channels
general
commands
Text Channels
main-channel
admin-channel
Text Channels
first-channel
```

I'd like to make command !br that will send message to the 1st channel in each server. But I can't because the Text Channels line counts as channel as well

[Here's little image what I mean by Text Channels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jYHG.png)

And I always get an error like this:

```
Cannot send messages in a non-text channel
```

So I'd like to skip these channels when they appear or delete them completely from the channel list.

Here is the full code of the command:

```
elif message.content.startswith('!br'):
    for server in client.servers:
        for channel in server.channels:
            if channel.permissions_for(server.me).send_messages:
                await client.send_message(channel, str(message.content[4:] )
                break
```

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check that the channel is a text channel, you would use `channel.type`. Documentation [here](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Channel).
You just need to check that channel should be of type `text`.

```
elif message.content.startswith('!br'):
    for server in client.servers:
        for channel in server.channels:
            if (channel.permissions_for(server.me).send_messages) and (channel.type == "text"):
                await client.send_message(channel, str(message.content[4:] )
                break
```

`channel.type == discord.ChannelType.text` will check if the channel is a text channel so that you can send a message.

Comment: This error message comes up:
AttributeError: 'Channel' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: can you please check now ? i have updated the answer

Comment: still the same  error message:
Cannot send messages in a non-text channel

Comment: you can send msgs only on text channel so you need to check for channel.type==discord.ChannelType.text . this is the fix i believe